# RegEx preg_match_all() and white spaces in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a Problem with RegEx and WhiteSpaces.

I want to split a Text in an Array which is marked with (....)

```
preg_match_all("/\([a-z0-9\s]+\)/i", $str,$a);
```

To catch whithe spaces I tried to use [\040] [\s] but nothing worked for me!

Is there a posibiltity to say [ANY Character DIGIT and WHITESPACES and special character] ?

greetz

fluxa

Comment: What do you mean by "marked with (....)" and why don't you use [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) if you want to split?

Answer (score 1):

You can also said "any characters but not a `)`"

With your example :

`preg_match_all("/\([^\)]+\)/i", $str, $a);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [lazy search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification) using`.*?` instead (which will stop matching as soon as it can, compared to greedy, `.*` which will match as much as possible).

Regex: `\((.*?)\)`

In code:

```
preg_match_all("#\((.*?)\)#", $str, $a);
```